# smart-table actions empties my table

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I followed all the steps described in the docs, I installed smart-table via bower, then I ref the script at index.html, then I added the module to one of my sub-modules, and I created my table:

```
<table st-table="vm.product_conditions" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="name">Nombre</th>
        <th st-sort="description">Descripcion</th>
        <th st-sort="status">Estado</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="condition in vm.product_conditions track by condition.id"
        ng-click="vm.detailProductCondition(condition.id, condition.name)">
        <td>{{ condition.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ condition.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ condition.status ? 'Activa' : 'Inactiva' }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table gets populated, but whenever I click on the column in order to sort it, the table gets empty, I also tried to implement the global search, and the same result, empty table...

Also, I get no error output, I tried to reproduce the error in a plunker, but to my surprise It worked there...

Is there any way to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading data asynchronous? If you are, you will need to have two collections, one that is the displayed collection and the other that contains all the items for the table.

Smart Table has a data attribute for `st-safe-src`.

The only way that I believe your tables would return a blank result, is if the `product_conditions` collection is somehow being interpreted as blank or undefined.

I would attempt to log out the collection to the console, before and after sorting the table and confirm if the collection is the same.

Reason why (from the documentation):

> smart-table first creates a safe copy of your displayed collection: it
>   creates an other array by copying the references of the items. It will
>   then modify the displayed collection (when sorting, filtering etc)
>   based on its safe copy. So if you don't intend to modify the
>   collection outside of the table, it will be all fine. However, if you
>   want to modify the collection (add item, remove item), or if you load
>   your data asynchronously (via AJAX-Call, timeout, etc) you will have
>   to tell smart-table to watch the original collection so it can update
>   its safe copy. This is were you use the stSafeSrc attribute

Comment: Yeah, it is loaded async, that makes sense... could you please make an example of it pls?

Comment: Haha, that was it, but could you explain me why this happens with async data?

Comment: @feniixx I updated my answer with the reason why (too large to comment). The documentation explains it better than I can paraphrase.